# Unable to link data from SXSSFWorksheet excel file

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Sequnce:

1) Using SXSSF to add data and generate excel file.

2) Using microsoft excel 'Data -> Get external data -> From file' shows no data in file, but they are 100% there.

[image]
[image]

But if you open the file in excel and 'Save as' then 'Data -> Get external data -> From file' functionality work fine.

Investigation shows that in sheet from 'Saved as' file dimension tag is `<dimension ref="A1:E4"/>` and in file that was generated with SXSSF dimension tag is `<dimension ref="A1:E1"/>`.

I tried next code but didn't helped:

```
sxssfWorkbook.getXSSFWorkbook
    .getSheet(sheet.getSheetName)
    .getCTWorksheet.getDimension.setRef("A1:" + 
        CellReference.convertNumToColString(nubmerOfCol) + 
        contentLenght)
fastWriteWb.write(fileOutputStream)
```

Is there any hot-fix for this?

Comment: This problem only occurs if the `SXSSFWorkbook` is created from a template `XSSFWorkbook`. Then the sheet dimensions are taken from that `XSSFWorkbook` and are not changed while adding new cells. Else if the `SXSSFWorkbook` is created from scratch using `new SXSSFWorkbook()` then the sheet dimensions always are `A1` only and the problem does not occur. I would call that an error in `apache poi` when one of the constructors `SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook ...)` is used.

Comment: You could file a bug report to `apache poi` about this. But please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with that bug report. Else you will not be very successfully.

Changing something in the underlying `CTWorksheet` java bean is not possible while using `SXSSF` because of the kind of streaming this does. The first part of the `worksheet`s `XML` is already be finally written when `SXSSFWorkbook` is created.

Comment: @AxelRichter I see. That is exactly what we do, generating from template. Thanks for your answer and explanation.